# MySQL procedure - Getting to work

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a procedure I've written to find out the top 10 items purchased per customer per day.

This is the first ever PL/SQL thing I've attempted.It doesn'tdo what I'm expecting it to do.

The logic I've used is to accept start date, end date & top 'x' sales that I'm interested in per customer. Then to loop through the unique customers table - `cust_table` & find the top 'x' per customer per day.

Could I please request guidance to get this working please?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `at _the _top`( in stDate  date,  in edDate  date, in lim int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cust TEXT;
    DECLARE custNames CURSOR FOR SELECT CUSTOMER FROM cust_table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 
    OPEN custNames;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH custNames INTO cust;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        WHILE(stDate <= edDate) DO
            #insert into top_cust(EVE_DATE,CUST_NAME,ITEM_ID,ITEMS_PURCHASED) (select EVE_DATE, CUST_NAME, ITEM_ID, SUM(ITEM_BUNDLE_SIZE) as ITEMS_PURCHASED_TOTAL from  cust_sales_hist where EVE_DATE = stDate and CUST_NAME = cust group by EVE_DATE, ITEM_ID order by ITEMS_PURCHASED_TOTAL desc limit lim);            
            SELECT concat('Custome - ', cust);
            SELECT CONCAT('Start Date - ', stDate);
            SELECT CONCAT('End date - ', edDate);
            SELECT CONCAT('Limit - ', lim);
            SELECT 
                EVE_DATE,
                CUST_NAME,
                ITEM_ID,
                SUM(ITEM_BUNDLE_SIZE) AS ITEMS_PURCHASED_TOTAL
            FROM
                cust_sales_hist
            WHERE
                EVE_DATE = stDate
                AND CUST_NAME = cust
            GROUP BY 
                EVE_DATE , 
                ITEM_ID
            ORDER BY 
                ITEMS_PURCHASED_TOTAL DESC
            LIMIT 
                LIM;
            SET stDate = date_add(stDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        end WHILE;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE custNames;
END
```

Comment: This is not PL/SQL. PL/SQL is the procedural language used in an Oracle database.  I don't know that MySQL has a particular name for its own procedural language.

Comment: Nice, someone out there is keeping fingers crossed for this question to be closed & also a down vote. Well done. it helps me. Thanks tons

Comment: Nope. It's just that that the question really is not clear and *It doesn'tdo what I'm expecting it to do.* is not a clear problem statement.  The long back and forth in the comments under @sgeddes' answer is usually a sign that the question needs more info/details (sample data, desired results, the usual...). This is not your first SQL question, so you should know better by now IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a stored procedure at all.  Instead, you could use a  single `select` statement using `user-defined variables`?

```
select eve_date, cust_name, item_id, sum(item_bundle_size) sumsize
from (
  select eve_date, cust_name, item_id, item_bundle_size, 
          @rn := if(@prevDate=eve_date and @prevItem=item_id, @rn + 1,
                    if (@prevDate:=eve_date, 
                        if (@prevItem:=item_id, 1, 1)
                        , 1)
                   ) rn
  from cust_sales_hist cross join 
       (select @rn:=0, @prevDate:=null, @prevItem:=null) t
  where cust_name = 'Cust 1' and
    eve_date between '2016-08-01' and '2016-08-02'
  order by eve_date, item_id
  ) t
where rn <= 2
group by eve_date, cust_name, item_id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/caf5d/5)

Comment: Thanks Sgeddes. I'll give this a go.If I were to make this call from PHP would this work without syntax errors. I'll give it a go myself, but thought of quickly checking if you know of a known error while calling it from PHP & needs to be worked around.

Comment: @usert4jju7 -- you'll want to use parameterized queries to pass in those 4 values (customer, start date, end date and limit) -- I hard coded those for examples above. Lots of examples on SO for that.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes. TOn the answer itself, I did give it a go. The output isn't limiting to say top 10 per day. It goes on to list the full set. I tried changing the `@rn`. Isn't this the limit ? I'm not familiar with user variables. Please could you tell me the purpose of this? How can limit to top 'x' items per customer per day please.

Comment: @usert4jju7 -- change `where rn <= 2` to whatever you need -- `where rn <= @limit`.  The row numbers are aggregated on date and item for that specific customer.  So where rn <= 2 would only sum bundle sizes for that group.  You can toggle that value in the fiddle to see how it alters the results.

Comment: hmm... I've updated the sample set - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0beb/4. With 8 values for customer 1 for 2016-08-01, it's displaying all 8 values when the limit is 4. :(

Comment: @usert4jju7 -- perhaps I misunderstood your question -- Is this what you're after instead: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0beb/19

Comment: Thank you. Not stillt here. it's closer I think though - I cleaned up some data - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0beb/15 - In here as you can the top 4 for customer, cust 1 is 7,6,8. The data for 2016-08-01 for customer 1 is  product with ID `('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 7, 600),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 6, 500),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 8, 378),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 4, 240),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 3, 130),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 5, 120),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 2, 110),
('2016-08-01', 'Cust 1', 1, 100),` while the fiddle says it's 1,2,3.

Comment: We need to sort each day by sum(item_bundle_size) in desc order before limiting the result set to `@limit`. I'm sorry to be a pain. I'm not able to do this with the query. Please, I look forward to your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118962/discussion-between-sgeddes-and-usert4jju7).